# Find the solution curve of $xdx+ydy=0$ passing through $(1,0)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Consider the D.E. 
$$
xdx+ydy=0.
$$
we want to find a solution curve  passing through the point $(x_{0},y_{0})=(1,0)$.

1. The general solution is $x^{2}+y^{2}=c$, where $c>0$ . So we find c=1 and hence the solution curve is $x^{2}+y^{2}=1$. But there is a little confusing thing:
2. I write the above equation in the form $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x}{y}$. The function $f(x,y)=-x/y$ is not cont. in $(1,0)$. But after using separation of variables we find
   $x^{2}+y^{2}=1$.
3. If I write the equation in the form $\frac{dx}{dy}=-\frac{y}{x}$ we have a unique solution curve passing the point $(1,0)$. The solution is $x=\sqrt{1-y^{2}}$. The interval of existence is $-1<y<1$.

My Questions:

What is the interval of existence in 1? Can I say it is $-1\leq x\leq 1$ or $-1\leq y \leq 1$. What happened exactly in cases 2 and 3?

Comment: i got $$x+y\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$

Comment: and what happens then?

Comment: The interval of existence cannot be an $x$-interval or a $y$-interval, instead one looks for functions $x(\ )$ and $y(\ )$ such that $x(t)x'(t)+y(t)y'(t)=0$ for every $t$ and one looks for some $t$-interval such that $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are well defined for every $t$ in this interval.

Comment: but if we write the D.E. in the case (2) or (3) we may think about $x-interval$ or $y-interval$.

Answer (score 1):

Just integrate. You have $\int xdx = x^2/2$, $\int ydy=y^2/2$ and you can put all the twos and integration constants in the $c$ in the equation $x^2+y^2=c^2$. Now your conditions gives $c=1$. So $x^2+y^2=1$. Sounds familiar ?

You must recognize the equation of a radius-1 circle ! It is then geometrically obvious that this cannot be defined for $|x|>1$... if you stick to reals !

You might know $cosh^2(x)-sinh^2(x)=1$, which is somewhat similar to your circle formula... Now if you have $x>=1$, let $x=cosh(t)$ and you formally have $y=\pm \sqrt{1-x^2} = \pm \sqrt{1-cosh^2(t)} = \pm \sqrt{-sinh^2(t)} = \pm i sinh(t)$. So outside of $[-1,1]$ you get solutions which aren't real, but define an hyperbola in the complex plane (that makes a 4D space, because two axes per variable !).

This is actually useful. For example, you have this Bezout theorem which states that two algebraic curves with degrees $d$ and $q$ intersect exactly $dq$ times... under the assumption that you know how to count !

The unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$ (degree 2) and the line $y=x+2$ (degree 1), for example, never collide. This theorem tells you that, if you count infinity points, multiplicity and imaginary intersection points, you must find exactly two of these, like in the case of $x^2+y^2=1$ and $y=x$ (where this is geometrically obvious).

Answer (score 1):

1. The solutions of the differential equation
   $$
   d\bigl[\tfrac{1}{2}(x^{2} + y^{2})\bigr] = x\, dx + y\, dy = 0
   \tag{1}
   $$
   are, as you say, circles $x^{2} + y^{2} = c$ centered at the origin.
2. Also as you say,
   $$
   \frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{x}{y}
   \tag{2}
   $$
   is not problem-free at $(1, 0)$: The formal deduction of (2) from (1) entailed dividing by $y$, which vanishes at $(1, 0)$. That means (2) is suspect as a starting point for separation of variables. (That said, (2) may be viewed geometrically as indicating the solution curve has a vertical tangent at $(1, 0)$.)
3. The equation
   $$
   \frac{dx}{dy} = -\frac{y}{x}
   \tag{3}
   $$
   is logically equivalent to (1) in some neighborhood of $(1, 0)$, so solving by separation of variables gives (a piece of) a solution to (1).

In the sense you ask, the interval of existence in 1. and 3., namely the largest interval in which
$$
x = \sqrt{1 - y^{2}}
\tag{4}
$$
is a smooth solution of (1), is $-1 < y < 1$. The resulting graph is precisely the intersection of the unit circle with the open half-plane $\{0 < x\}$, namely the largest neighborhood of $(1, 0)$ in which (3) is equivalent to (1).

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrew! Is it possible to have an i.v.p in the following form:  $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x}{y}$ with $y(1)=0$ ? I mean that according to your discussion we have to say that this problem has no solution?

Comment: That's right: In the (usual) sense of "there exists a solution defined in some open interval about $x = 1$", that IVP has no solution. (And, you're very welcome!)